# How to fix when installing puppet client on centos 7 with dockerfile getting Error: Package: ruby-augeas-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64

Tags: centos, docker, puppet

I'm trying to install `puppet-client` on `docker` `centos-latest` with this `dockerfile`

```
# Base OS
FROM centos

# Install puppet
ENV PUPPET_VERSION 3.7.3
RUN rpm --import https://yum.puppetlabs.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs && rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
RUN yum install -y yum-utils && yum-config-manager --enable centosplus >& /dev/null
RUN yum install -y puppet-$PUPPET_VERSION
```

but when I run it i get

```
---> Package ruby-irb.noarch 0:2.0.0.598-24.el7 will be installed
---> Package ruby-shadow.x86_64 1:2.2.0-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libruby.so.1.8()(64bit) for package: 1:ruby-shadow-2.2.0-2.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: ruby-augeas-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-deps)
           Requires: libruby.so.1.8()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:ruby-shadow-2.2.0-2.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-deps)
           Requires: libruby.so.1.8()(64bit)
Error: Package: ruby-augeas-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-deps)
           Requires: ruby(abi) = 1.8
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
INFO[0003] The command [/bin/sh -c yum install -y puppet-$PUPPET_VERSION] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How to fix that `dockerfile` script? (Note: I wish to use the latest `centos`)

Answer (score 0):

resolved by replacing:

```
http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
```

with:

```
http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm
```